# How can I make a blur background that appears onPress of a button and when clicking back on the background it un-blurs it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

> I also want to when I click on the background and there are other pressable things/buttons on this background, they are not being pressed unless the state is back to when it is un-blurred (basically: only the blurred background can be pressed when the screen is blurred). If you need an example look at twitter mobile: when you click on the post (+) button, it blurs the background but when clicked back it un-blurs it. (Must work for IOS and Android).

Comment: Just use a blurry image at 50% opacity or less in an img tag with position absolute, height 100%, width 100% and an OnClick event that toggles a ref style display to none or block

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this..

In **CSS** create 2 classes - First one with the blur and second one without.

In React create 2 functions - 1 onclick for the blur-button and 1 onclick for the close button. These functions should change the class of body.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
$('body').addClass('blur'); });
```